# Flutter: How to backup user data on Google drive like WhatsApp does?

Tags: flutter, google-drive-api, backup

I want to to backup data in **Backups** on user **Google Drive** account and restore them.

I have seen apps, like **WhatsApp** that allow users to login through google drive and do periodic backup to the user cloud.

I don't want to use firebase cloud since the data is access by the user himself and not other users and it will be costly if the data is large. Is there any available package can do this? Or tutorial otherwise how to achieve this in flutter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Step 1**

You need to have already created a Google Firebase Project, and enable Google Drive API from Google Developer Console. Note that you need to select the same project in Google Developer Console as you have created in Google Firebase.

**Step 2**

you need to log in with google to get googleSignInAccount and use
dependencies

```
 googleapis: ^0.54.0  
 googleapis_auth: ^0.2.11 



class GoogleHttpClient extends IOClient {  
 Map<String, String> _headers;  
 GoogleHttpClient(this._headers) : super();  
 @override  
 Future<http.StreamedResponse> send(http.BaseRequest request) =>  
     super.send(request..headers.addAll(_headers));  
 @override  
 Future<http.Response> head(Object url, {Map<String, String> headers}) =>  
     super.head(url, headers: headers..addAll(_headers));  
}
```

Upload File to Google Drive

```
_uploadFileToGoogleDrive() async {  
   var client = GoogleHttpClient(await googleSignInAccount.authHeaders);  
   var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);  
   ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();  
   var file = await FilePicker.getFile();  
   fileToUpload.parents = ["appDataFolder"];  
   fileToUpload.name = path.basename(file.absolute.path);  
   var response = await drive.files.create(  
     fileToUpload,  
     uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),  
   );  
   print(response);  
 }
```

Download Google Drive File

```
Future<void> _downloadGoogleDriveFile(String fName, String gdID) async {  
   var client = GoogleHttpClient(await googleSignInAccount.authHeaders);  
   var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);  
   ga.Media file = await drive.files  
       .get(gdID, downloadOptions: ga.DownloadOptions.FullMedia);  
   print(file.stream);  
   
   final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();  
   print(directory.path);  
   final saveFile = File('${directory.path}/${new DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}$fName');  
   List<int> dataStore = [];  
   file.stream.listen((data) {  
     print("DataReceived: ${data.length}");  
     dataStore.insertAll(dataStore.length, data);  
   }, onDone: () {  
     print("Task Done");  
     saveFile.writeAsBytes(dataStore);  
     print("File saved at ${saveFile.path}");  
   }, onError: (error) {  
     print("Some Error");  
   });  
 }
```

Comment: How to upload app database file to drive using flutter.

Comment: @Omar Will this folder or the file show up inside user’s google drive account ?

Comment: @DivyamDhadwal no, the appDataFolder is hidden from the user you can refer to the docs https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata for more info

Comment: @OmarMahmoud Got it! But how is that differentiated..I mean other apps will be also using the same folder, right? How do someone differentiate the data that belongs to App A from that of App B..If all of them are using the same folder ?

Comment: Any idea for the comment above ??

Comment: "This folder is only accessible by your application and its contents are hidden from the user and from other Drive apps." refer to the docs https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/appdata for more info

Answer (score 4):

Its easy but you have to go through a series of Steps to complete it.

**1. Enable Google Drive API**

click on the link to google console :
https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library?project=diary-app-339509

- Create a new project and enable Drive API on the project.
- Create an OAuth client Id for android and IOS
- You will have to fill a lot of details to create it , read through the page and fill it
- copy Client ID for future use

[create project and enable API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTZgI.png)

[Create OAuth client id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p8Qcd.png)

[form to fill to make OAuth client id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvo27.png)

**2. Make project available for external use .**

[for testing add test user email address](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIOMZ.png)

*Now comes the coding part on flutter*

**3. Add the following packages to *pubspec.yaml***

```
  googleapis: ^7.0.0
  googleapis_auth: ^1.3.0
  flutter_secure_storage: ^5.0.2
  url_launcher: ^6.0.0-nullsafety
```

**4. Get authentication from google and store the Auth details for future auths**

Use the following class for storing Auth Details

```
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';

class SecureStorage {
  final storage = FlutterSecureStorage();

  //Save Credentials
  Future saveCredentials(AccessToken token, String refreshToken) async {
    print(token.expiry.toIso8601String());
    await storage.write(key: "type", value: token.type);
    await storage.write(key: "data", value: token.data);
    await storage.write(key: "expiry", value: token.expiry.toString());
    await storage.write(key: "refreshToken", value: refreshToken);
  }

  //Get Saved Credentials
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>?> getCredentials() async {
    var result = await storage.readAll();
    if (result.isEmpty) return null;
    return result;
  }

  //Clear Saved Credentials
  Future clear() {
    return storage.deleteAll();
  }
}
```

**5.Finally use this class for saving your file to Drive**

```
   import 'dart:io';
    import 'package:googleapis/drive/v3.dart' as ga;
    import 'package:googleapis_auth/auth_io.dart';
    import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
    import 'package:path/path.dart' as p;
    import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
    import 'package:personal_diary/app/utils/secure_storage.dart';
    import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';
    
    const _clientId = "379503391554-6d33j9e6lan7lg0ac7sj81026u8nigs8.apps.googleusercontent.com";
    const _scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'];
    
    class GoogleDrive {
      final storage = SecureStorage();
      //Get Authenticated Http Client
      Future<http.Client> getHttpClient() async {
        //Get Credentials
        var credentials = await storage.getCredentials();
        if (credentials == null) {
          //Needs user authentication
          var authClient = await clientViaUserConsent(
              ClientId(_clientId),_scopes, (url) {
            //Open Url in Browser
            launch(url);
          });
          //Save Credentials
          await storage.saveCredentials(authClient.credentials.accessToken,
              authClient.credentials.refreshToken!);
          return authClient;
        } else {
          print(credentials["expiry"]);
          //Already authenticated
          return authenticatedClient(
              http.Client(),
              AccessCredentials(
                  AccessToken(credentials["type"], credentials["data"],
                      DateTime.tryParse(credentials["expiry"])!),
                  credentials["refreshToken"],
                  _scopes));
        }
      }
    
    // check if the directory forlder is already available in drive , if available return its id
    // if not available create a folder in drive and return id
    //   if not able to create id then it means user authetication has failed
      Future<String?> _getFolderId(ga.DriveApi driveApi) async {
        final mimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.folder";
        String folderName = "personalDiaryBackup";
    
        try {
          final found = await driveApi.files.list(
            q: "mimeType = '$mimeType' and name = '$folderName'",
            $fields: "files(id, name)",
          );
          final files = found.files;
          if (files == null) {
            print("Sign-in first Error");
            return null;
          }
    
          // The folder already exists
          if (files.isNotEmpty) {
            return files.first.id;
          }
    
          // Create a folder
          ga.File folder = ga.File();
          folder.name = folderName;
          folder.mimeType = mimeType;
          final folderCreation = await driveApi.files.create(folder);
          print("Folder ID: ${folderCreation.id}");
    
          return folderCreation.id;
        } catch (e) {
          print(e);
          return null;
        }
      }
    
    
      uploadFileToGoogleDrive(File file) async {
        var client = await getHttpClient();
        var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
        String? folderId =  await _getFolderId(drive);
        if(folderId == null){
          print("Sign-in first Error");
        }else {
          ga.File fileToUpload = ga.File();
          fileToUpload.parents = [folderId];
          fileToUpload.name = p.basename(file.absolute.path);
          var response = await drive.files.create(
            fileToUpload,
            uploadMedia: ga.Media(file.openRead(), file.lengthSync()),
          );
          print(response);
        }
    
      }
    
      Future<void> _downloadGoogleDriveFile(String fName, String gdID) async {
        var client = await getHttpClient();
        var drive = ga.DriveApi(client);
        ga.Media file = await drive.files.get(gdID, downloadOptions: ga.DownloadOptions.FullMedia);
        print(file.stream);
    
        final directory = await getExternalStorageDirectory();
        print(directory);
        final saveFile = File('$directory/${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}$fName');
        List<int> dataStore = [];
        file.stream.listen((data) {
          print("DataReceived: ${data.length}");
          dataStore.insertAll(dataStore.length, data);
        }, onDone: () {
          print("Task Done");
          saveFile.writeAsBytes(dataStore);
          print("File saved at ${saveFile.path}");
        }, onError: (error) {
          print("Some Error");
        });
      }
    
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer  @Jeslin.  But this takes the user to an external browser screen and stays there even after authentication. Is it possible to have some sort of redirection to bring the user back to the app?

Comment: @rehman_00001 in my case it actually redirected back to the main app after authentication.

Comment: Hi @JeslinJacob I see you saved the refresh token. Does that mean that the credentials will expire at some point and we need to refresh the token manually ourselves?