# App doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure error

Tags: flutter, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm trying to upload a file to google drive through my flutter app, I've done all the steps mentioned in the below thread(2nd Answer)[thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68955545/flutter-how-to-backup-user-data-on-google-drive-like-whatsapp-does)

and I created an icon button on my app screen and called the uploadFileToGoogleDrive() method

```
googleDrive.uploadFileToGoogleDrive(file);
```

when I click on the icon button I get redirected to the below page

[image]

Please help

Answer (score 0):

you have the redirect uri set to `Http://localhost:35211`

Redirect uris must be **https** not **http**.

Configure your application so that it runs https.

Comment: from where can I change that?

Comment: probably in your ide some where. What do you use to run your flutter app.  [How to run flutter web application locally with https?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61446577/how-to-run-flutter-web-application-locally-with-https)

Comment: I'm running this app on my mobile phone and ide is android studio

Comment: Look in the settings for android studio then.  It should be able to set that things run https.